# Play button border-radius issue in IE

Tags: html, css

I want to have a play button for the video content. Play button is not appearing perfectly circular and on IE border of circle appears to be clipped.

```css
.play-link::before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background-color:#0076ff
}

.play-link::after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:16px;
  top:13px;
border-top:6px solid transparent;
border-bottom:6px  solid transparent;
 border-left:11px solid #fff
}
.play-link {
  position:relative;
  height:40px;
  line-height:40px;
  padding-left:55px;
  line-height:40px;
  text-decoration:none;
  display:inline-block;
  color:white
}

body {
  background-color:black
}
```

```html
<a class="play-link" href=""> Watch introduction video </a>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/bhupi1011/d48e1t59/) is the fiddle for the same

[image: in IE 11 play button radius appears cropped]

Comment: Hey Bhupendra, i am not able to find out any problem in IE browser. i think your code is working fine.

Comment: if you see attached image , it appears to be cropped on  right side ie11 . Also it does not appear perfectly circular

Comment: The problem exists on that Fiddle, don't know why. If you check the [embedded fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhupi1011/d48e1t59/embedded/result,css,html,js), than it looks correct.

Comment: Try add with overflow hidden for `:before` element

Comment: Don't add the tags (`CSS`)  in front of you question title.

Comment: that's just how IE renders this. if you create an empty div element and style it with `height: 40px; width: 40px; border-radius: 50%; background-color:blue` you will see the exact same result.